# Safely patch additional attributes to Django HttpRequest

Tags: python, django

### Background

In certain middleware, I want to add some additional attributes to it, like so:

```
def process_request(self, request: HttpRequest):
    request._additional_info = {}
```

and then I can access it in the view function:

```
def update_information(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if hasattr(request, "_additional_info"):
        request._additional_info["updated"] = True
```

It works just fine.

However, since `_additional_info` only presents in runtime, there is no way for mypy to know that it exists, and thus making the `hasattr` check necessary.

### Question

My question is: is it possible to create a class called `CustomHttpRequest` that **behaves exactly the same** as `HttpRequest` except that it explicitly has additional attributes like `_additional_info`?

### Expected Result

With that, I should able to convert `HttpRequest` to `CustomHttpRequest` in the middleware, and change the type hints for `request` in the view functions to `CustomHttpRequest`.

```
class ConvertRequests(MiddlewareMixin):
    def __call__(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
        converted_request = CustomHttpRequest(request)
        return self.get_response(converted_request)
```

No more `hasattr` will be needed, and now mypy and autocomplete should know that request may have the attribute `_additional_info`.

```
def update_information(request: CustomHttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    assert request._additional_info is not None:
    request._additional_info["updated"] = True
```